# RESTAR STOCK EN LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

Alguna idea de como se puede usar ese proceso en laravel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta serias mis tablas que tiene una relacion
y este seria mi codigo para poder almacenar los datos

```
$pedido = pedido::where('id_pedidos',$request->id_pedidos)
        ->get();
        $cuantos = count($pedido);
        if($cuantos==0)
        {   
          
            $pedido = new pedido;
            $pedido->id_pedidos = $request->id_pedidos;
            $pedido->fecha = $request->fecha;
            $pedido->cliente = $request->cliente;
            $pedido->status = $request->status;
            $pedido->save();
            
            $pedido_bodega = new pedido_bodega;
            $pedido_bodega->id_pedidos = $request->id_pedidos;
            $pedido_bodega->id_bodega = $request->id_bodega;
            $pedido_bodega->cantidad = $request->cantidad;
            $pedido_bodega->precio_uni = $request->precio_uni;
            $pedido_bodega->save();

           
        }
        else
        {
        
         
            $pedido_bodega = new pedido_bodega;
            $pedido_bodega->id_pedidos = $request->id_pedidos;
            $pedido_bodega->id_bodega = $request->id_bodega;
            $pedido_bodega->cantidad = $request->cantidad;
            $pedido_bodega->precio_uni = $request->precio_uni;
            $pedido_bodega->save();
         
        }
```

Pero no tengo ni idea de como tomar el dato de cantidad del formulario y descontar dicha cantidad en la bodega

Agradecería mucha su ayuda y espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: Haciendo un `UPDATE` a la fila indicada indicando que la cantidad - el valor tomado del stock

Comment: $bodega = new bodega;
            $bodega->cantidad -  $request->cantidad;
            $bodega->update();  Seria algo como esto ?

Comment: En estos casos debes probar el código pierdele el miedo, así si no queda ya empezamos por algo

Comment: Si ya le estuve intentando con varias formas que se, pero no se como aplicarlo para que funcione, tienes alguna idea de como seria solo para tomarlo como punto de partida

Comment: Precisamente para poderte ayudar sería muy útil si editas tu pregunta y lo colocas